# Singular value decomposition of identity matrix

Tags: matrices, svd

If you run a SVD on a identity matrix, $I = U S V^T$, will the matrix $S$ also be an identity matrix?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Can I ask why? Some explanation would be great

Comment: You have to work out $I^TI$ and $II^T$ and figure out their eigenvalues.

Comment: @Corgam that's a bit of a confusing question to answer.  I would say that by the definition of the SVD, it is obvious that $S$ must be $I$; perhaps you're working with a different definition.  Could you add the definition of SVD that you're starting with to the body of your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, given any $m \times n$ matrix $A$ with its SVD

$$
A = U \Sigma V^T
$$

the matrix $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with singular values of $A$ on the diagonal entries. Furthermore, these non-zero singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ (or $A^TA$ which has the same set of eigenvalues).

Now in your case, $I^TI = I$, and the only eigenvalue of $I$ is $1$, therefore, the singular value of $I$ is $1$ which implies that $\Sigma = I$.